Executing function inside {#each} loop uses values in reversed order, sveltekit
I'm looping over some messages in a chat app and adding date division element that shows the date of sending of the messages under it, but when I have multiple messages sent on the same day, the divider doesn't work as expected and goes between messages that should be in the same date group. I have a function that gets the date and formats it, then returns an object with the formatted date(dd-mm-yyyy) and time(hour-minute AM/PM). When I add a function inside the {#each} loop to console.log the result of the formatDate(), it shows in the console in reversed order. For example, if I have a message sent at 8:35 AM, and a second one sent at 8:37 AM, in the console it shows the 8:37 first, then the 8:35. The array that contains the messages is sorted in chronological
order, and when I display the indexes of elements in the array or log them to the console, they are in order. I think there might be something about some asynchronous stuff going on that makes the loop reference values in a different order.
let datesGroup: string[] = [];

// Function to get the moment of the day and of the year when the message was sent
function formatDate(dateStr: string, addToArray: boolean = false): MessageDate {
    if (!dateStr) return { ofYear: '', ofDay: '' };

    // Set pointers in time
    const date = new Date(dateStr);
    const todayDate = new Date();
    const { hour, minute, meridian, day, month, year } = getDateValues(date);
    const yearDate = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
    const time = `${hour}:${minute} ${meridian}`;
    const today = `${getDateValues(todayDate).day}-${getDateValues(todayDate).month}-${getDateValues(todayDate).year}`;
    let isNewDate = false;

    // Check if a message is part of a different date group
    if (datesGroup.indexOf(yearDate) === -1) isNewDate = true;

    // Add the date divider to the array
    if (addToArray && isNewDate) datesGroup = [...datesGroup, yearDate];

    return {
        isNewDate: isNewDate,
        ofDay: time,
        ofYear: today === yearDate ? 'Today' : yearDate
    };
}

function getDateValues(date: Date) {
    return {
        minute: date.getMinutes() > 9 ? date.getMinutes() : '0' + date.getMinutes(),
        hour: date.getHours() > 12 ? date.getHours() - 12 : date.getHours(),
        day: date.getDate() > 9 ? date.getDate() : '0' + date.getDate(),
        month: date.getMonth() > 9 ? date.getMonth() : '0' + date.getMonth(),
        year: date.getFullYear(),
        meridian: date.getHours() > 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'
    };
}

{#each messages as message (message.id)}
    {#if formatDate(String(message.sentat), false).isNewDate}
        <div class="date-display">
            {formatDate(String(message.sentat), true).ofYear}
        </div>
    {/if}
    <div>
        {#if message.from != $page.data.USER.id}
            <img
                class="msg-profile-picture"
                alt="pfp"
                src={getProfilePicture(message.from, currentRoomMembers)}
            />
        {/if}
        <div class="msg-content" class:sent-by-me={$page.data.USER.id === message.from}>
            {#if message.from !== $page.data.USER.id}
                <span
                    ><a href="/profiles/{message.from}">{GetUsername(message.from, currentRoomMembers)}</a
                    ></span
                >
            {/if}
            <div class:shortened={message.text.length > 1400 && !message.shortened}>
                {message.text.length < 1400
                    ? message.text
                    : message.text.split('').slice(0, 1400).join('')}
                {#if message.text.length > 1400}
                    <button type="button" class="show-more">Show more</button>
                {/if}
            </div>
            <span>{formatDate(String(message.sentat), false).ofDay}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
{/each}

I tried referencing individual messages by their index, but it still was reversed
